how to Retrieve Data from a Data Mining Model to display it via SSRS report?
I need to display prediction graphs using SSRS to make this accessible to some users who need it. To do this, here are the steps successfully completed using VS community 2019:
1- I created a multidimensional and SSAS analysis project
2- I added a data source, a data source view, a cube, a dimension and a data mining structure
3- I successfully deployed the SSAS project
4- In the "data mining model forecasts" view, I can make predictions normally and I got the following DMX query which allows me to make the predictions:
DMX query:
SELECT Predict([Tmp].[sales],5) From   [Tmp]

5- subsequently I created an SSRS report and I connected normally my SSAS data source above
6- I added a dataset and in the dataset properties I imported the DMX query above into the dataset query area
7- in the properties of the dataset, in the Fields section I observe the following: field name: Expression; source field: expression
8- I inserted a tablix object in my report and I linked it normally to the dataset above with the “expression” data that I saw in the dataset properties.
9-when I run a preview of my SSRS report I don't see any results that I can see well in my SSAS project with vS.
can anyone help me to display prediction graphs using SSRS?

I found the solution by modifying the DMX request
